# Array in c programming

Tags: c

I need help with this one:

Implement function `int array_reader(int *array, int size)` that reads integer values using `scanf` into pre-allocated array. Parameter size gives the maximum length of the array, and the maximum number of values to be read. If user does not give a valid integer (as can be seen from return value of `scanf`), the array ends, even if the maximum size was not yet reached. The function returns the final size of the array at the end, which can be smaller that the incoming size parameter, if the user finished the input with non-valid integer.

Below is an example how this function can be tested:

```
int array[10];
int n = array_reader(array, 10);
printf("%d numbers read\n", n);
```

I have done (but it is not ready yet):

```
int array_reader(int *array, int size)
{
    int array[10]; 
    scanf("%10d", &array[10]);
    if (scanf("%10d", &array[10]) =! 10)
    {
    break;
    }
  }
```

Can you help me to continue? Thanks.

Comment: scanf returns number of inputs read successfully....it doesnt check the input value

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you think your code does? Why didn’t you finish the program yourself, where did you get lost?

Comment: scanf doesn't read 10 ints like you thought, and you're not using `size` anywhere

Answer (score 3):

There is no function in standard C that can read into an array from a user like that, you have to loop over the array, reading values one by one.

You also have a few other problems:

- You make a local variable `array` that shadows the argument, so you read only into that local array and not the one passed as the argument.
- when you use `10` as index you are indexing out of bounds for the array. Indices range from zero to size - 1.
- You don't return anything, even though you tell the compiler you would. That means that the assignment in the calling function will assign an unknown value.
- The `break` statement does nothing outside of a loop.
- The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function returns the number of values it converted, not the number of characters it read. So if you're scanning for only one item then `scanf` will return either `1`, `0` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this

```
int array_reader(int *array, int size){
    int count = 0;
    do{
        if(1!=scanf("%d", array++))
            break;
        ++count;
    } while(count < size);
    //To be clear the buffer when there is bad input?
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers!

You can make it also with for loop? Like this:

int array_reader(int *array, int size){

for(int count = 0; count < size; count++){

```
    if(1!=scanf("%d", array++))
        break;
```

else
    return count;
}
}